# Damp Foundation marks at one location

Tags: foundation

First time homeowner, slowly discovering items around the foundation. I recently found that a part of my foundation is slightly discoloured. Is this a sign of foundation problem? There are no cracks etc, just discolouration.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1pDE.jpg

Is this serious? Thank you!

Comment: Looks perfectly normal to me.

Comment: There are some dark lines on the surface, is that water and mold?

Comment: Very fine cracks -- normal

Answer (score 1):

That is obviously a rock veneer wall sitting on your concrete foundation wall.

If you look closely you’ll see a small hole (called a “weep hole”) in the mortar joint directly above the rag and sitting on the foundation wall… it even has a small plastic tube they use to keep the hole open.

This wall has a small (thin) air space (about 1-2” wide) behind the rocks AND a waterproof membrane on the structural system (wood framing, or masonry wall, etc.) behind the air space.

The membrane extends down the inside of the wall and funnels all the moisture that gets past the rock veneer to the small weep holes spaced along the wall. When this moisture runs out of that air space, it probably brings dirt and dust that runs down the wall and causes the discoloration.

It’s normal.